# How to plot a specific subset of data from a data file with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot a single point, from a line in data file, that has many other lines and two rows. I don't know how to select a single line in gnuplot, not the entire file of data. Any suggestions please???

Answer (score 3):

In case the point(s) you want to plot are not characterized by the line number, but by some value in one column, you can use this trick in `using` :

```
plot '-' using (($1==0)?$1:1/0):2 with points
-1 1
0  2
1  3
e
```

This can be used to plot e.g. only points with a positive x-coordinate (change to `($1>=0)?$1:1/0`), or also, using the `$0` pseudo-column which contains the line number, to select specific lines in a more versatile way than `every` :

```
plot 'data.dat' using (((int($0)%3!=0)?$1:1/0):2 with points
```

Here we plot 2 lines out of 3, of course you can also select one line only with `($0==LINE)?$1:1/0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter out. In gnuplot this is done with the keyword `every`.

Since you do not provide the file you want to plot here is a possible hint based on this datafile `data.dat`:

```
10 62
11 95
12 74
13 33
14 70
```

youplot the point at the third line (12,74) like this:

```
plot 'data.dat' every ::2::2 w p
```

based on the file structure, this might vary.

Maybe if you have to do it several times it's good to set a variable:

```
n=2
plot 'data.dat' every ::n::n w p
```

so that once plotted, you can do:

```
n=3; replot
n=10; replot
...
```

Please read carefully the `help every` command in gnuplot